# Factorize $x^4-4$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^4+1)[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> What are the irreducible factors of $x^4-4$ in $K[x]$ where $K=\mathbb Q[x]/(x^4+1)$?

Clearly $x^4-4=(x^2+2)(x^2-2)$, but from here I'm not sure what to do. I tried showing that $\sqrt{2}\in K$ or $\sqrt{2}\not\in K$ but couldn't do either.

Comment: What tools do you have available for solving this sort of problem? For example, could you use Galois theory, or are you looking for a more elementary approach?

Comment: @DanielHast Preferably more elementary approach, I haven't covered Galois theory yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$K=\mathbb Q[x]/(x^4+1)=\mathbb Q(a)$, where $a^4+1=0$. This shows that $a$ is a primitive $8$th root of unity, so we may take $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(1+i)$. Show that $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,i)$. Now finish the proof.

Comment: Is it correct to say that since $\alpha$ is a primitive 8th root of unity and primitive roots of unity form a cyclic group then we have $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8)$ for any primitive 8th root of unity $\zeta_8$?

Comment: Yes, you can say that.